# how to open the app store when clicking button

Tags: swift, app-store

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1wTc.png)I want to open the app store when I click a certain button but, I have looked everywhere, and the code I have tried takes me to a safari link or doesn't do anything at all. can anyone help me? what i want it to achieve is that i hit the button and it opens up the app store with my specified app

UPDATE: i tried the method below and it opened oped up safari saying it could open the page

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried and clarify what exact result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What method below? There's no code in your question. Update your question with actual code that you used. Explain what it does and what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zenprogrammer79 if your using the iOS simulator the link won't work because there is no App Store on the simulator but it should work on a real iOS device

Answer (score 0):

zenProgrammer79 if you have a link to another app in the App Store, you can put this code in the section of where your button gets pressed (the IBAction) (objective-c)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"link to the application link looks like https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/sugar-calculator/id1000071935?mt=8"]];
```

if you are using swift i believe this will work

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/sugar-calculator/id1000071935?mt=8")!)
```

if this doesn't work then your link to the app is probably wrong.

Comment: FYI - The question is tagged Swift.